# Assets packaging tool like jammit for JSP, Java EE projects?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, jammit

We've got a lot of javascript and CSS files in our Java EE project. We're wondering if there's a tool to help you package(minification) these files, like the jammit tool in Rails?

For instance, in a JSP page, i want to do something like this:

```
<tag:include_stylesheets :common, :workspace, :media => 'all' />
<tag:include_javascripts :workspace />
```

In development, no packaging is performed, so you'll see a list of individual references to all of the JavaScript and CSS files. When we package a war file, it compiles javascript into a single file(or a few files and only include the one that's used)

Is there any tool like that for JSP?

Answer (score 5):

Yes - [Jawr](http://jawr.java.net/) - "Bundling and compression for javascript and css"

(Actually, building your own is rather simple, but it's better to reuse the library)

Answer (score 3):

There are several more options:

1. [pack:tag](http://www.galan.de/pages/packtag) - Comprehensive JavaScript and CSS packaging solution
2. [jso](http://js-optimizer.sourceforge.net/) - JavaScript Optimizer
3. [wro4j](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/) - Web Resource Optimizer for Java

Disclaimer: Though I'm working on one of these, the answer is unbiased.